# Category Label crums are not displaying in multi-select view in edit form admin magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category-products, category-listing, labels

I am creating the category restriction module, when i edit particular record then all data are filled fine except category (Label Crums).

[image]

In edit page, multi-select categories are selected but label crums are not displaying in field.

I want to get like below::
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data provider, use this inside contructor.

```
$this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
```